# Search for lowest/highest value in the date array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

What is the best formula to get the lowest and highest values from `column C` for every date?

Need to fill `F` and `G` columns as a result

[image]

Link: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxLit5vOf9FIjEp4TOEWLFNoCB4yS5mYXXMXo2tvtiM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({LEFT(A2:A; 10)*1\C2:C}; 
 "select Col1,min(Col2),max(Col2)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1
  label Col1'date'"))
```

[image: 0]